# How do I specify the path for ES6 import in Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, google-closure-compiler

Using the latest version of Closure Compiler, I can't seem to get ES6 modules to load no matter how I specify the module's path in the `import` statement.

To test this, I created two very simple files in the same directory.

defaults.js:

```
const defaults = {color: "#F44336"}
export {defaults}
```

test.js:

```
import {defaults} from 'defaults.js'
console.log(defaults.color)
```

When I just run test.js without attempting to process it with Closure Compiler, it works as expected and imports the module. But trying to compile it produces the error:

`test.js:1:0: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "defaults"`

This is the command line I'm using:

```
compiler \
--module_resolution NODE \
--compilation_level ADVANCED \
--language_in ECMASCRIPT_2020 \
--language_out ECMASCRIPT_2020 \
--js test.js
```

I've tried specifying the path to the module file in test.js as a fully qualified absolute path, and various forms of relative path, and nothing has worked. I also tried adding the module file as a `--js` option for the compiler, but no dice.

It seems like such a simple thing but I have not found a solution by extensive googling, either. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of the compiler you are using?

Comment: It's the latest Linux version: v20210601.

Comment: Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler-linux

Comment: I can't believe I'm the only one who has ever tried to do this with Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated your files (note the difference):

defaults.js

```js
const defaults = {color: "#F44336"}
export {defaults}
```

test.js

```js
import {defaults} from './defaults.js' // relative path!
console.log(defaults.color)
```

**Compilation**

You **MUST** specify all files involved in the compilation with `--js`.

```
$ cc --module_resolution NODE --compilation_level ADVANCED --js defaults.js --js test.js
console.log("#F44336");
```

<sup>`cc` is just an alias to my copy of the Closure compiler</sup>

---

**Addendum**

I'm pretty sure that your biggest mistake has to be this:

```js
import {defaults} from 'defaults.js'
```

This was never going to load the file on disk but instead was looking for a NPM package called `defaults.js` in your dependencies.